# How to create backup of a sql database in a ci/cd pipeline

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, github-actions

**Usecase**

Within a pipeline i am trying to take a backup of a database(AWS RDS) and store the dump to s3 before i do any migration changes. I am using github actions for the ci/cd pipeline.

**Problem**

I have a problem with trying to connect to the database, i get the following error:

> mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface
> can be insecure. mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user
> '***'@'redacted_ip' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

I get an access denied error, even though i know the credentials are correct because i have tested it locally. The only difference is, locally im prompted to input a password and in the CI i want to avoid being prompted for the password so i've entered it via a command line arguments.

**pipeline.yml**

```
name: pipeline

on: [ push ]

env:
  PROD_DATABASE_HOST: ${{ secrets.PROD_DATABASE_HOST }}
  PROD_DATABASE_USER: ${{ secrets.PROD_DATABASE_USER }}
  PROD_DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PROD_DATABASE_PASSWORD }}
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Install mysql
      run: |
        sudo apt-get -y update
        sudo apt-get -y install mysql-client
        mysql --version
    - name: Take backup
      run: |
        mysqldump -h $PROD_DATABASE_HOST \
          -u $PROD_DATABASE_USER \
          -p="$PROD_DATABASE_PASSWORD" \
          --port=3306 \
          --single-transaction \
          --routines \
          --triggers \
          --databases  test_gg  > rds-dump.sql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using the `--defaults-extra-file` flag for mysqldump https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html. It allows you to store your configuration into a .cnf file and later reference it.

**pipeline.yml**

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Install & Setup MySQL
      run: |
        sudo apt-get -y update
        sudo apt-get -y install mysql-client
        echo MySQL VersionIs: 
        mysql --version

        crds="[mysqldump]\nuser=$PROD_DATABASE_USER
\npassword=$PROD_DATABASE_PASSWORD\nhost=$PROD_DATABASE_HOST\nport=3306"
        echo -e $crds > login.cnf

        filename=$(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S)-backup
        mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=login.cnf \
          --single-transaction \
          --events \
          --routines \
          --triggers \
          --databases test_gg | gzip > ${filename}.gz
        stat -c %s ${filename}.gz
        echo Done
```